# Are smearing functions in QFT operator independent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, regularization

For a scalar field $\hat{\phi}(x)$, the smearing is performed by convoluting the operator $\hat{\phi}(x)$ with a smooth function $f(x')$ which has support in the neighborhood of the point $x$.

Is this smearing function dependent on the operator at hand, or depends only on the point $x$ about which it is defined? In case it depends on the operator at hand, is the existence of a smearing function which is able to smear all possible operators in the theory guaranteed?

My specific problem is this: Suppose if I want to look at the smeared field operator and its conjugate momenta at a general point $x$. Can I use the same smearing function for both the operators, or is the smearing function necessarily different for both these operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of not using the scalar fields $\Phi(x)$ itself but the operator-valued distributions they define

$$f \mapsto \Phi(f) = \int f(x) \Phi(x) d x $$

is to make all amplitudes distributions. In this approach you are interested maybe in Correlators

$$\langle \Phi(f) \Phi(g) \rangle = \int \langle \Phi(x) \Phi(y) \rangle f(x) g(y) dx dy $$

which takes to arbitrary text functions $f,g$. You may choose $f = g$, but calculating this will in general give you not enough information to infer $\langle \Phi(x) \Phi(y) \rangle$. This is analogous to how in the calculus of variations, one needs to take into account arbitrary variations in order to obtain equations of motion (cf. the *fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations).

One a more physical level, one might want to reconstruct $\langle \Phi(x) \Phi(y) \rangle$ by considering $\langle \Phi(f) \Phi(g) \rangle$ and $f,g$ becoming more and more peaked at $x$ and $y$ respectively. This doesn't work anymore if all we have is one function $f$.

Comment: Convolution and cross-correlation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQm6ZP1F6ms